# Как установить блокировку исходящего доступа к IP?

Tags: firewall, ip, windows-xp

Возникла проблема - какое-то приложение постоянно пытается соединиться с определёнными IP-адресами.
Проверка через http://ip-whois.net/ показывает, что там ничего нет (никаких сайтов/доменов). Блокировка через файл **HOSTS** не работает.

Есть ли возможность заблокировать эти адреса или узнать, что за процесс пытается отправить какие-то данные?

Система - **Windows XP SP3**, антивирус - **AVAST,**  файрвол - **NETLIMITER**.
Так же стоит **Malwarebytes Anti-Malware**, который и показывает блокировку адреса к вредоносному сайту каждые 2-3 секунды. Но не могу найти в логах, где указывается программа/процесс, которая пытается это сделать.

Может, кто-нибудь подскажет, как правильно настроить **AVAST**/**NETLIMITER** на блокировку **исходящих** соединений или способ отловить этот процесс/программу?

Comment: вы не на сисадминский форум зашли здесь программисты сидят. вам правила в фаервол внести надо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В *nix я бы попробовал отловить процесс, используя скрипт из netstat -a --tcp и lsof, а вот в винде не силен...

Поищите, может в ней тоже есть какие-то аналоги этих утилит.